# Combine two arrays in specific order

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to combine these two arrays:

```
A = ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird"]
B = ["John", "Doe", "Foo"]
```

I must take the first element of the first array and then the first element of the second array, then the second element of the first array and the second element of the second array and so on. It has to be in this exact order:

```
["Dog", "John", "Cat", "Doe", "Bird", "Foo"]
```

Comment: Use lowercase for variable names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) to get `[[A[0], B[0]], [A[1], B[1]], ...]`

```
A.zip(B)
# => [["Dog", "John"], ["Cat", "Doe"], ["Bird", "Foo"]]
```

Flattening it will give you what you want:

```
A.zip(B).flatten
# => ["Dog", "John", "Cat", "Doe", "Bird", "Foo"]
```

---

**UPDATE** alternative using [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
(0...A.size).map { |i| [A[i], B[i]] }
# => [["Dog", "John"], ["Cat", "Doe"], ["Bird", "Foo"]]
(0...A.size).flat_map { |i| [A[i], B[i]] }
# => ["Dog", "John", "Cat", "Doe", "Bird", "Foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(2*A.size) { |i| i.even? ? A[i/2] : B[i/2] }
  #=> ["Dog", "John", "Cat", "Doe", "Bird", "Foo"]
```